# Is it possible to create a pointer-free function?

Tags: c, function, memory-management, free

We got a 2D allocation as follows:

```
char** arr;
short i = 0;

arr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
for( ; i<10; i++)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
}
```

which allocates `arr[10][100];`
Then we need to free it like so:

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(arr); i++) free(arr[i]);
free(arr);
```

So i was thinking to make a function that saves time, space and confusion and i have this:

```
void pfree(void** data)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<sizeof(data); i++)
    {
        free(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Is the function relevant, if not is there another way?

Comment: This isn't valid in C, since `sizeof(arr)` is a compile-time operator. It should be returning 4 or 8 bytes (for the size of the pointer itself) in all likelihood.

Comment: And the freeing is in wrong order, and...

Comment: Yes unfortunatelly that is so, but i'll fix it in the question.

Comment: @deviantfan i don't think the order of the freeing matters.

Comment: @Edenia: Yes it does, else you´re accessing memory which doesn´t belong to you = undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Edenia It does. You must free every `arr[i]` and only then you can free `arr`.

Comment: @Filipe i don't know... thats what the question is about.

Comment: @Filipe well it works the same way with both orders though. But thats not the question anyway.

Comment: @Edenia Working as expected is a valid form of undefined behavior. You should switch the order to avoid undefined behavior, otherwise you're lucky that it doesn't crash

Comment: @Filipe allright, i will change the order to avoid u/b :)

Comment: As for pfree, continuing where Jeff stopped: You´ll need a second parameter to pass the size used instead of sizeof(...) inside the function. And your current pfree does only one of the two freeing parts.

Comment: This is not a 2D array but an emulation of it. In modern C you should just use `char (*arr)[100] = malloc(sizeof(char[10][100]));` and `free(arr)`. No need for complicated functions.

Comment: @deviantfan Yes, it will be better if i actually implement freeing of both. So basically thats all, i have to pass an argument for manually size parameter?

Comment: @JensGustedt: What if Edenia actually wants that, for different "line" length etc.? We don´t know here it will be used.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt believe me, the C im using is far from modern.

Comment: @Edenia: Yes, that should be everything.

Comment: @deviantfan Well then.. thank you. It is a bit disappointing that you have to declare the size manually.

Comment: Well...that´s C :) See sharths answer for code...

Comment: @Edenia, where do you get that from? Many people are stuck in this form of acient C.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt
Game-Editor is 2D Game Engine created in 2002. Since then.. the language that the engine uses is not even upgraded.

Comment: @Edenia, 2002 this already has been acient. And the latest C standard dates from 2011.

Comment: @Jens Yes. As a matter of fact the C im using is even under C89
Even the compiller don't like declaring variables inside a loop.

Comment: So you see, it is not C that is stuck in the latest millenium. Upgrade your toolchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's completely reasonable to create functions like this. Especially if it:

1. Increases the clarity of your code
2. Decreases the likelihood of bugs

I would probably write a `malloc_2d()` and `free_2d()`:

```
void free_2d(void **arr, size_t count) {
    int i;

    if (arr) {
        for (i=0; i<count; ++i)
            free(arr[i]);
        free(arr);
    }
}

void** malloc_2d(size_t count, size_t elem_count, size_t elem_size) {
    int i;        
    void **arr = calloc(count, sizeof(void *));

    if (arr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (i=0; i<elem_count; ++i) {
        arr[i] = calloc(elem_count, elem_size);
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            free_2d(arr, i);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Alternatively, a common mechanism is to encode a 2-dimensional array into a 1 dimensional array. So, let's say we want a 16x4 array.

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 6 * 4);
for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        arr[i*4 + j] = compute(i, j);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time spent on this. What you have wrote is perfect. :)

Comment: Since this is about C, you can use real 2D arrays instead of computing an index into a 1D array. Just replace the allocation in your last example with `int (*arr)[4] = malloc(6*sizeof(*arr));` and the array access `arr[i*4 + j]` with `arr[i][j]`. The memory layout is the same, but the compiler will do the index computation for you.

Comment: @cmaster: I'd argue that the memory layout in your code is better. (And there's changes that could be made in my code to reach that goal as well). That being said, it complicates things, and that's probably not helpful to Edenia. Additionally, your suggestion requires knowledge of the array width at compile time (which I usually don't know until runtime).

Comment: It seems, I have good news for you: in C array sizes **don't** have to be compile time constants anymore (I believe since C99). That is one big place where C is much more flexible than C++ which retains the compile time constant rule.

Comment: Isn't `free_2d(arr, i);` instead of `free_2d(arr, count);`? because allocation might fail in loop before `count` is reached.

Comment: @TheMask: Whoops. I meant to have a fix in there for that. Should be good now.

Comment: Are void** and int**( or any other type ) compatible? I don't think so. If so, this violates aliasing rules. +edit: You can use void** type outside but then you have to cast everytime which is error prone and makes the code unclear.

Comment: @self.: I believe you are correct. Do you know of a reasonable solution? (nothing comes to my mind...)

Comment: @sharth You can't really do it with an array of pointers( unless you use void* and get/set functions ), but since OP doesn't need a jagged array, just allocate a single block of memory and return to a pointer to an 2d array. int (*arr)[inner_size] = malloc( sizeof( int ) * size * inner_size ) ;

Answer (score 3):

First you need to understand that [**pointers are not arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/2455888). `sizeof` operates differently on both types.
When the parameter of `sizeof` is a pointer then it simply returns the size of pointer, which is either 4 or 8 bytes.
When the parameter of `sizeof` is an array name then it returns the size of the entire array. For example; for `int a[10]`, `sizeof(a)` will return `10 * sizeof(int) = 40` bytes (taking 4 bytes for an `int`).
So, the loop

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(arr); i++) free(arr[i]);
```

this doesn't work as you expect. You need to change it to

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) free(arr[i]);
```

And change your function to

```
void pfree(void** data, int size)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I was confused because the debug aways says that arrays are actually pointers. And it makes sense. I understand the difference like.. arrays don't point to another adress but their next one.

Comment: No. Arrays are not pointers which does make sense!  [**pointer arithmetic and array indexing (that) are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are different**](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html).

Comment: Ahh i see. Arrays point to an adress though, thats why i assume them pointers but they are not like the real ones, marked with the astersk.

Comment: YES. I included links in my answer and comment. That would be helpful.

Comment: That is helpful. It is aways nice to refresh your knowledge about the pointers.

Comment: I think is valid to mention C99's sizeof and VLAs either. OP might find a working program where size of array is take at runtime using `sizeof` operator and turns confusing.

Comment: @TheMask; I think that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an array is encoded in its type, so whenever you pass only a pointer to its first element, that information is lost, `sizeof` will only yield the size of the pointer. Thus you cannot use the signature the way you wrote it, you must supply the size of the array:

```
void pfree(void** data, size_t count) {
    for(size_t i = count; i--;) free(data[i]);
    free(data);
}
```

---

Note, that the lines

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(arr); i++) free(arr[i]);
free(arr);
```

is wrong for memory allocated with

```
char** arr;
short i = 0;

arr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
for( ; i<10; i++) {
    ...
```

as well, because `sizeof(arr)` only gives the size of a pointer again!

Comment: From all the nice responses.. i think thats trully clear for anyone already. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the freeing by allocating enough space for the whole 2D array.  This works quite well if elem_count * elem_size is a multiple of 4 on a 32 bit system or a multiple of 8 on a 64 bit system.

```
void pfree(void **arr, size_t count) 
{
    if (arr)
    {
        /* arr[0] points to a contiguous array so no need to go through
           the whole array */
        free(arr[0]);
        free(arr);
    }
}

void** pmalloc(size_t count, size_t elem_count, size_t elem_size)
{
    int i;        
    void **result = calloc(count, sizeof(void *));
    /* Allocate enough space for the entire array */
    int arr_size = elem_count * elem_size;
    char *arr = calloc(count, arr_size);

    if (arr == NULL || result == NULL)
    {
        /* may get a memory leak */
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i=0; i<count; ++i)
        result[i] = &arr[i * arr_size];

    return result;
}
```